# WCF Data Services : how to call POST Operations with big body

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-data-services

How to call WCF Data Services Operations from the WCF Services Client ?

I have this operation on my service :

```
[WebInvoke(Method="POST")]
public void Add(int ContractId, string Partners)
{
    ...
}
```

How do I call this operation from my client ? my client is a C# based application. bearing in mind that the Partners string is a very very long one. it's a concatenation of the partners Ids like : "1,2,3,4, ... 990".

I have tried doing the following :

```
        string requestString = string.Format("Add?contractId={0}&Partners={1}",  ContractId, groupIdParam);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl +
            requestString);

        request.Method = "POST";

        var response = request.GetResponse();
```

but I receive the error : "HTTP 414 : Request Uri too long"

Comment: I believe query strings have a limit on characters - I want to say 255, but that may vary depending on platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently OData doesn't support passing parameters for service operations (that's what the WebInvoke method is) in the body of the POST request. All the parameters are passed in the URL, and thus they have to be pretty small (usually something below 2048 characters, depends on your web server, proxies and so on).

Comment: Hi Vitek, thanks. I just realised that. How do I pass in very long strings then ? is there any way to get around the length limitation ?

Comment: In order to get around this limitation, Is it possible to send multiple requests as a batch ? If so, how do I do that ?

Comment: You can send multiple requests in a batch - see http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/batch.

Comment: Is there any example of doing that using C# ? All I see is how to format the requests but I don't exactly get what classes I can use in C# for that.

Comment: The WCF DS Client doesn't support arbitrary batch requests, so use that to call service operations won't help. You could use Microsoft.Data.OData.dll (which is part of the latest WCF DS CTP: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/10/13/announcing-wcf-data-services-oct-2011-ctp-for-net-4-and-silverlight-4.aspx), there's a batch writer in it. But we don't have any samples I know of yet.

Comment: sure, there's a batch writer in the latest WCF DS CTP but it's a sealed class with no public constructors and no static methods. How do you use such a class ? (ODataBatchWriter)

Comment: In short: var m = new ODataMessageWriter(message); var b = m.CreateODataBatchWriter(); b.WriteStartBatch ...;

Comment: Note that you will have to implement the "message" yourself, the library takes IODataRequestMessage, but that should be pretty easy. See for example this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/10/14/introducing-the-odata-library.aspx for the general usage (no batch though).

Comment: Actually - there is a batch sample there - the blog post above has attached sample project, in it in FileResponseSamples there's a WriteBatch method which writes a batch payload.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you aren't performing a POST-request. A POST request provides the information in the request-body, which is why it is used especially for large data-sets. You have to provide both `contractId` and `partners` in the request-body. You can use the `HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()` method to get a stream, to which you then write the parameters.

This link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP) describes the structure used to specify the name-value pairs within the request-body.

So you could write something like this (untested):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl + "Add");
using (Stream bodyStream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(bodyStream))
{
    writer.Write("contractId: {0}", contractId);
    writer.Write("partners: {0}", String.Join(",", partners);
}

request.GetResponse();
```

**Edit**
As Vitek Karas stated this isn't possible. I just looked at it from a client perspective not the service.

Comment: Thanks @J.Tihon for your answer, but running it, I run into this error at the server : "400: "Bad Request - Error in query syntax."

Comment: Did you set `request.Method = "POST"`, I've forgot to add it. Also you can use a tool like "fiddler", which allows you to inspect the messages sent to and from the WCF service.

Comment: now, I can send the data successfully to the service with no "bad request" exception but no body content is being received (at server level)